# MacMini Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 Headless Boot, Not Accessible, Not Booting

Tags: networking, 14.04, reboot, headless, mac-mini

I have a 14.04 Ubuntu Desktop installation on a MacMini running headless in my closet. When I boot the server, it will not assign itself an IP address until I login to a user session. This means anytime I reboot, the machine is not accessible via the network until I attach a monitor and login.

I am pinging the IP address of the server from my laptop on the same network and getting nothing until I login.

Am I missing something here? I feel like this is an easy/obvious fix but I am missing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added `auto eth0` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp` lines to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file and rebooted, the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the answer.

The MacMini will not boot unless it detects a monitor attached. There is no way around this at the BIOS level since there is no BIOS.

The SOLUTION? Plug in a DVI(male)-VGA(female) converter where you short out a few VGA pins using 100ohm resistors.

Source: http://imaginaryrobots.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/headless-mac-mini-hardware-hack/

[image: Exact pin-out diagram]
[image: Showing the converter with resistors]
<sub>(source: [nickoneill.name](http://blog.nickoneill.name/images/dvivgaadapter.png))</sub>